# Diff CDF V2 Document

Tags: linux, unix, diff, cdf

I have some documents in `CDF V2` format. I need to compare them. I have tried to use diff, but it is not the right way. How can I reach the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need CDF Toolkit which has CDFcompare,

```
Program        Description
-------        -----------
CDFcompare     This utility is used to display the differences between two CDF 
               files. It has many options that can be specified to select what
               and how the data entities in CDFs to be compared.
```

Please see below link for more details (FAQ) on CDF.

http://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/html/FAQ.html

Answer (score 1):

If your CDF V2 documents are in Microsoft's CDF/CFBF/OLE2 format, you might also try the Python packages http://www.decalage.info/olefile (a low-level implementation) and http://www.decalage.info/python/oletools (a high-level interface with various extraction tools and a browsing GUI).